# obj-C, Json + Coredata from remote server - without a local database / databastore, best approach?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to figure out how my new app should handle data.

In previous projects i've avoided core data due to the learning curve and I've ended up using arrays.

However, this project is a little more complicated.
There's a remote server which provides json content.
I've already got the custom authentication written.

The server will aggregate the data.

I'm worried about performance, having to access the server each time I want to get any data.

However, my main question is, can i use coredata as a kind of wrapper rather than having a local database / datastore ?

Comment: Core data is efficient. Just you have to put extra effort then its really very easier than SQLite.. Go for it.. I learned few days ago only..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CoreData can have as backing store: XML, SQLite, Binary and Memory.. So you can use an in-memory store... if this is your question...

Answer (score -1):

> I'm worried about performance, having to access the server each time I
>   want to get any data.

Of course if you request some data from server, it takes more time and you need to be connected. So if it is critical consider storing some already received data on device.

CoreData is not very useful as a "wrapper".
When you receive JSON results from server most natural way is parse them into native collection of NSDictionarie's and NSArray's with lib like JSONKit, then you can simply use this results. To fill coredata storage you anyway need to parse data and them assign CD-managed objects from parsing results.

But if you want to **store**  results either on disk for future use or in memory just to organize them into your custom classes then CoreData is a good choise.